# Cant detect the file in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hey guys am new to ajax I have a php file and a ajax file. I just want to detect the php file from the ajax so I have send a request in ajax like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
  } else {
 console.log('file not fetched');
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","first.php?m=babe",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
}
loadXMLDoc();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My php file

```
<?php
include("ajax.html");
$p = $_REQUEST['m'];
if($p == 'babe') {
    echo true;
}
```

When I run the ajax.html on localhost it doesn't show me any message in the window nor in the console.

Can you guys tell me why is it like this?

Thanx for the help

Comment: And did you get any errors in the console ?

Comment: What about the "Network" tab? Also, where are the files located, and what do your URLs look like?

Comment: @adeneo the console is blank'

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen both the php file and js file is the same folder ...in the www directory

Comment: So you never get an alert, nor a console log, nor an error ? Seems unlikely.

Comment: @adeneo yeah thats what am asking .why is it like this ??..both the files are in same directory

Comment: I repeat, what about the "Network" tab? If you do not see anything there then the request was never sent. If the request was sent then you can inspect it further, to see what happened.

Comment: `xmlhttp.status==200` What if it’s not 200?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen the network tab shows ajax.html 200 ok etc etc

Comment: `onreadystatechange` and `else{console.log('file not fetched');}` and a blank console: something’s not right…

Comment: I think there’s a missing `{` after the first `if` statement… and after the first `else`.

Comment: @Xufox i dont know what am doing wrong ..thats what am asking the network tab shows ajax.html and status code like Status Code:304 Not Modified

Comment: @Xufox am sorry it was just a typing error. i edited it

Comment: I'm getting plenty of errors in the console, for instance `xmlhttp` is not defined outside the `loadXMLDoc()` function, I really can't see how you're not getting any errors with that code ?

Comment: The `open` and `send` calls seems to be inside the `readystate` handler, so those are never executed etc.

Comment: Learn to indent your code properly !

Comment: @codingbabe I did post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your brackets were wrong:

```
function loadXMLDoc(){
var xmlhttp;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){ // This bracket was missing
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{ // This bracket was missing
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
  else{
    console.log('file not fetched');
  }
} // This bracket was on the wrong place (it enclosed the .open() and .send())

xmlhttp.open("GET","first.php?m=babe",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

loadXMLDoc();
```

Also, a simpler way of defining the callback function is:

```
xmlhttp.onload=function(){
  if(xmlhttp.status==200){
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
  else{
    console.log('file not fetched');
  }
}
```